# Need to set all rows value based on the top row results

Tags: mysql

I need to select the top row AND l1.activityId = t2.activityId  Then  I need to be able to set ALL rows of a.scheduleType to be equal to 'error' - NOT just the rows where the above is true. Currently I can get the value to change based on each rows results of l1.activityId = t2.activityId but that will not help for my over all outcome that I need.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE reportFreeCoolingTrackerNoErrors (
        IN fromDate varchar (50),
        IN toDate varchar (50),
        IN timeZone varchar (50))

    BEGIN
            DECLARE startDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE endDate varchar (50);
            DECLARE mylogID Int;

             SET startDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000);
             SET endDate = FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000);

SELECT 
   l1.item31985,l1.item31987,a.scheduleType,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987)*(time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)))) / 3600  AS kwDifference,
    ((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) *  (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , ':' ) +1))) AS cost,
    (((l1.item31985 - l1.item31987) *  (substr(l.details, instr(l.details , ':' ) +1)))
    *(time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600)) AS costT,
      time_to_sec(timediff(t2.completed, l1.completed)) / 3600 AS coolingHours,
      time_to_sec(timediff(endDate, startDate)) / 3600 AS totalTimeRange,
    (CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(fromDate/1000)),'UTC', timeZone) )AS startingDate, 
    (CONVERT_TZ( (FROM_UNIXTIME(toDate/1000)),'UTC', timeZone) ) AS endingDate,DATABASE() AS databaseName,
     CASE
        when l1.activityId = t2.activityId THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS errorCheck  

  FROM logs l 
      INNER JOIN groups g ON g.groupId = l.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g1 ON g.parentId = g1.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g2 ON g1.parentId = g2.groupId
      LEFT JOIN groups g3 ON g2.parentId = g3.groupId                
      INNER JOIN activities a ON l.logId = a.logId 
      INNER JOIN log1644 l1 ON a.activityId = l1.activityId 
      INNER JOIN log1644 t2 ON t2.recordId = l1.recordid + 1
      INNER JOIN items i ON l.logId = i.logId AND i.name LIKE '%KW%'
      INNER JOIN users u ON l1.userId = u.userId AND i.name LIKE '%KW%'
     WHERE i.itemID = "31985"  AND  l1.activityId = 1257
      AND l1.started 
        BETWEEN startDate
            AND endDate
     ORDER BY l1.recordId,l1.started;

    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Could you not use two queries to achieve it ?

Comment: I am not sure how I would go about that. I have tried SO many different options!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To select a TOP row, Select ONLY the first row in a descending order data set:

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM TABLE
ORDER BY <your field> DESC
LIMIT 1 ;
```

Since you are doing this in a stored procedure, you can select a.scheduleType into a variable and then execute a select with that variable in the where clause.

Comment: That would SELECT the top row - I WANT to select all rows BUT based on what the top row returns I need to set ALL rows a.schedule type to error

Comment: Since you are doing this in a stored procedure, you can do this in two steps:
First- you can select a.scheduleType into a variable using the query and then execute a select with that variable in the where clause.